# How to overload an equal operator in c++?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Hello i'm trying to overload '=' operator with StringBad class.
I'm trying to copy values from one instance of class StringBad to another(when they are initialized), without memory leaks. What am I doing wrong?
My compiler noticed an error:

```
In file included from main.cpp:4:0:
main.h:15:64: error: member functions are implicitly friends of their class [-fpermissive]
     friend StringBad & StringBad::operator=(const StringBad & t);
                                                                ^
main.h:49:53: error: definition of implicitly-declared ‘StringBad& StringBad::operator=(const StringBad&)’
 StringBad & StringBad::operator=(const StringBad & t){
```

---

```
StringBad AA , DD;

DD=AA
```

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring> 
using namespace std;  
class StringBad{
    private:
    char *str;
    static int num_str;
    int len;   
    public:
    StringBad(const char *s);
    StringBad(const StringBad &s);
    StringBad();
    ~StringBad();
    friend ostream & operator<<(ostream & os , const StringBad & st);
    friend StringBad & StringBad::operator=(const StringBad & t);
    };
int StringBad::num_str = 0;
StringBad::StringBad(const char *s){
        len = std::strlen(s);
        str = new char[len + 1];
        strcpy( str, s);
        num_str++;
        cout<<"Obiekt utworzony w 1 konstr, istnieje "<<num_str<<"size:"<<\
        num_str * sizeof(StringBad)<<endl;
}
StringBad::StringBad(){
        len =4;
        str = new char[len + 1];
        strcpy( str, "c++");
        num_str++;
        cout<<"Obiekt utworzony w 2 konstr, istnieje "<<num_str<<"size:"<<\
        num_str * sizeof(StringBad)<<endl;
    }
StringBad::~StringBad(){ --num_str; delete [] str; cout<<"((!))Jest jeszcze:"<<\
num_str<<endl;}
StringBad::StringBad(const StringBad & s){
    len = s.len;
    str = new char [len+1];
    strcpy(str, s.str);
    num_str++;
    cout<<"KK kopiujacy"<<endl;
    }

ostream & operator<<(ostream & os , const StringBad & st){
    os<<st.str;
    return os;
 }

StringBad & StringBad::operator=(const StringBad & t){
    if(this==&t)
        return *this;
    delete [] str;
    len = t.len;
    str = new char [len+1];
    strcpy(str, t.str);
    return *this;

}
```

Comment: You don't need to friend the copy-assign operator.  Remove the `friend` from the beginning of the declaration.

Comment: Also, is there a reason you're making your own string class and not just using `std::string`?

Comment: Im just trying to overoad an equal operator :) Tour advice dodn't help... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The copy assignment operator shall be a member function of the class.

Declare it simply as

```
StringBad & operator=(const StringBad & t);
```

Comment: error: ‘StringBad& operator=(const StringBad&)’ must be a nonstatic member function
 StringBad & operator=(const StringBad & y){

Comment: This builds, you've made some mistake

Comment: @Xos Lamoo I showed the declaration that must be inside the class definition. Can you read what I wrote? Then reread my post anew.